# stop html textarea from ignoring null characters

Tags: html

i was wondering if there was any way of stopping html from ignoring null characters in strings. I have a textarea component and i am writing a string to it. This string contains null characters. However for some reason, html strips the string of the null characters. I need the null characters because the string is actually a cypher text and i need all the characters (including the null ones) when decrypting.

I'd appreciate any help :)

I can not use a place holder for the null characters because adding anything to the string corrupts it since it's a cypher text.

Comment: If the purpose is to share the cipher text, then hex it first and share that.

Comment: @GetSet but i would like to display the cypher text. I am building a playground for encryption and decryption

Comment: Display it as hex. Null for example would be displayed as `00`. You would convert each byte (0..255) of the cypher to its equivalent value in hex. In this way you can display it with no issues.